# how to set a variable dynamically - python, pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dynamic, dataframe

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>>from pandas import Series, DataFrame

>>>rawData = pd.read_csv('wow.txt')
>>>rawData 
     time       mean    
0    0.005           0                   
1    0.010      258.64                   
2    0.015      258.43                   
3    0.020      253.72          
4    0.025           0                   
5    0.030           0                   
6    0.035      253.84             
7    0.040      254.17           
8    0.045           0                   
9    0.050           0               
10   0.055           0      
11   0.060      254.73    
12   0.065      254.90      
             .
             . 
             .
489  4.180      167.46
```

I want to apply below formula and get 'y' when I enter 'x' value dynamically to plotting a graph.

> y = y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0/x1-x0)

If 'mean' value is 0(for example index4,5 index8,9,10)
    1) Ask question  "Do you want to interpolate?"
    2) If yes, enter the 'x' value
    3) calculating using formula (repeat 1-3 until answer is no)
 
    4) If answer is no, finish the program.

```
     time(x-axis) mean(y-axis)         
0    0.005                 0                   
1    0.010            258.64                   
2    0.015            258.43                   
3    0.020  <--x0     253.72      <-- y0        
4    0.025                 0                   
5    0.030                 0                   
6    0.035  <--x1     253.84      <-- y1         
7    0.040  <--x0     254.17      <-- y0             
8    0.045                 0                   
9    0.050                 0               
10   0.055                 0      
11   0.060  <--x1     254.73      <-- y1
12   0.065            254.90      
             .
             . 
             .
489  4.180            167.46
```

variable x0,x1,y0,y1 is determined when they are located outside between '0' value.
***How to get a variable dynamically and calculate?*** 
Do you have any good idea to design program?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.mean [i]=0:
        answer=input ("Do you want to interpolate?")
        if answer="Y":
            x1 = df.loc[df.mean > 0].index[1]  
            y1 = df.loc[df.time > 0].index[1] 
            Interpolate eqn
        else:
            Process
    else:
         x0 = df.time [i]
         y0 = df.mean[i]
```

Excuse typos,  working on mobile phone.